# Testing robust regression model made from training set in R

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, robust

I have done a robust regression on my training-dataset and would now like to see whether the model fits the test-training set. However, I do not know how to do this. I have already made sure my test-set only contains the variables used in the model, that is the firs step I believe, but what is next?

[image: Picture of my model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: the next step involves using the model you've generated to predict the outcomes of the test/validation dataset. This can be completed using the `predict()` function in R, where your first argument is your model `H1.final.model` and the second is the test/validation set.

This will output predictions of the data set based upon the coefficients you've established in your regression model. You can cross-reference these predicted outcomes against the defined outcomes of your test set in a number of different ways.